# Apache Commons IO download only first PDF page

Tags: java, pdf, apache-commons-io

I'm using Java with Apache Commons-IO to download a PDF but I only want to get the first page, is there a way I can do it? 
Here's the piece of code that gets the whole doc:

```
public void getPDF(String route) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(route);
    File file = new File("file.pdf");
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
}
```

Comment: The data dir the contents of a single page in a pdf may be distributed all over the pdf file. If your remote site allows for range requests, one probably could implement something that collects all objects from the remote pdf that are required for a given single page. In general, though, I doubt that is efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation to your code, you may use a new Document to hold only first page of given PDF file.

```
 URL url = new URL(route);
 File file = new File("file.pdf");
 FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);

 PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
 PDDocument document = null;

int pageNumberToRead=0;

try {   
    document = new PDDocument();   
    document.addPage((PDPage) pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNumberToRead));   
    document.save("basepath/first_page.pdf");  
    document.close();  
}catch(Exception e){}
```